# In FireBug, how do I make the HTML code persist (open to the ame place in the code) when I do a page reload?

Tags: html, firebug, reload

When I refresh a page, I would like to have Firebug return to the same place in the HTML code view (code tree open)

Answer (score 0):

[Firediff](http://www.incaseofstairs.com/firediff/) helped me to export the generated HTML when I wanted to do that (a long time a go, really). It might be worth a try.